# Modal Bottom Sheet isnt transparent althought background set too transparent

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet, material-components-android

All my modal BottomSheets have a white background above them and are not transparent as intended.

I tried opening the view via a separate Fragment like this:

```
 ContextMenuPlaylistFragment contextMenuPlaylistFragment = new ContextMenuPlaylistFragment();
 contextMenuPlaylistFragment.show(fragmentManager,"contextmenu playlists");
```

and like that:

```
View modelBottomSheet = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.context_menu_playlist, null);
BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(mContext);
dialog.setContentView(modelBottomSheet);
dialog.show();
```

This is my BottomSheetFragment:

```
public class ContextMenuPlaylistFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.context_menu_playlist, container, false);
    }
}
```

And this is my BottomSheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/transparent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button_playlist_search"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/search_playlist"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button_playlist_rename"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/rename_playlist"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_playlist_delete"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/delete_playlist"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I put it in two LinearLayouts to try and make the background transparent. 
I also tried it with one `LinearLayout` that doesn't change the background and has height `"wrap_content"`

[image]

Comment: Are you using a material theme in your app?

Comment: Do you want to make full screen with transparent background?

Comment: yes i am using a material theme in my app and no i wanna make it to the height of wrap_content with transparent background

Answer (score -1):

Please check if you have set the android:background attribute in the  "AppTheme" style to white. If so, delete it or set it to transparent will solve the problem.